# Images pushed via docker(az acr) shows as untagged in the portal

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-registry

I am attempting to push a docker image to az acr through a linux ubuntu 20.04 machine

I run the commands
Docker login Registry
Docker tag source:tag registry/target:tag
docker push registry/target:tag

All these run without an error and I get a repository in the portal but it doesn't show with tags, the manifest also shows it as quarantined. Has anyone experienced this before or any ideas?

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried with windows with same command see if its working in windows?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to push the image with tag to `Azure Container Registry` using login server of the `acr` using following commands:

```bash
docker build --tag test_image:latest .  #to build image with tag
az acr login --name imagetag #logged in in ACR
docker tag test_image:latest imagetag.azurecr.io/azure_image:azurelatest # I am using login server of ACR
docker push imagetag.azurecr.io/azure_image:azurelatest #pushed image to ACR
```

[image]

## `OUTPUT`:

[image]

[image]

For Reference check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container?tabs=acr,bash,azure-cli&pivots=programming-language-python#publish-the-container-image-to-a-registry)